# jquery submit() doesn't work when using anonymous funcion

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit a form using submit(), and indeed it works fine when I only use submit() without any anonymous function inside, the problem is when I use the anonymous function like this then it stops working

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert("alert never shows up :( ");
});
```

This is my code: (sorry for mixing jQuery and getElementsByTagName, old guy's fault)

```
var uform = $('#createItem1');
if(uform[0]) {
    // UI's first validation image extension before server-side
    var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png"];
    var arrInputs = uform[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        //Checks if image is of valid extension
        if (oInput.type == "file"){
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        // this works fine
                        $('#createItem1').submit();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    $('a#linkStep1').trigger('click');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Again, as soon as I try to replace current submit() for something like this, it stops working

```
$('#createItem1').submit(function() {
   alert("something");
});
```

Any idea why is not working?

Comment: Try switching to `$('#createItem1').trigger('submit');` instead

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why would you want to pass an anonymous function to the submit trigger? Maybe you want the anonymous function to be called once the form was successfully submitted? If so, you need an ajax request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a function (anonymous or otherwise) to the [`.submit()` method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) that defines a handler that will be run when the form gets submitted, but it doesn't actually cause the form to submit. If you pass no parameters to `.submit()` *that* makes it submit.

If you want to define a handler and submit at the same time you can do this:

```
$('#createItem1').submit(function() {
   alert("something");
}).submit();
```

`.submit()` with no parameters is a shortcut for `.trigger("submit")`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because either there is no valid object for the selector or the object(s) returned are not forms.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a anonymous function to `submit` method it will not submit the form but will attach a handler which will be executed when the form is submitted.

To submit the `form` just say.

```
$('#createItem1').submit();
```

If any `submit` event handlers attached they will be  triggered automatically.